# Batch print pdf files in alphabetical file name order

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I have a folder with multiple PDF files and I want them to be printed by alphabetical order (by file name).

at the moment I have this:

```
dir /b | sort > %temp%\files.tmp
for /f %f in (%temp%\files.tmp) do AcroRd32.exe /t %f "\\MOANB604\NLCAN02"
del %temp%\files.tmp
```

When I activate the batch file nothing works. whats wrong?
printer path: file://MOANB604/NLCAN02

Comment: Use `dir /O:N /B`. That will order the files by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your code by using the `dir`'s output directly in the `for`:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /O:N /B *.pdf') do AcroRd32.exe /t %i "\\MOANB604\NLCAN02"
```

Comment: When I activate the batch file nothing happens.
The location of the folder is H:\PALY\Export\Test printer\Test folder

Comment: If you're running from a batch file you should use `%%i` instead of `%i`. Sorry 'cause I test it directly in the cmd.

Comment: I replaced the %i with %%i and still nothing, i see some lines in cmd and then it disappears.

Comment: for debugging don't run it by mouseclick - open a `cmd` window and run it manually to be able to see any messages. If your filenames (may) contain spaces, surround `%i` with quotes: `"%I"` (or `"%%i"` in a batch file)

Comment: ''for /f %%i in ('dir /O:N /B') do AcroRd32.exe /t %%i "//SVRP0001B604/NLAPOCAN02''

Comment: I get this error in CMD
C:\Users\kiewan\AcroRd32.exe /t Contacts "//MOANB604/NLCAN02"
'AcroRd32.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @KiewanSanee I edit to get only .pdf files. I assumed where you run the script there's only .pdf files. Is AcroRd32 in your environment path locations?

Comment: @dcg yes there are only PDF files inside the folder.

Comment: @KiewanSanee For the error you post you should provide the absolute path for AcroRd32.exe, something like `C:\Program Files\...\AcroRd32.exe`

Comment: ... and put it into quotes, as is probably contains spaces.

Comment: Now im getting a access denied message, i think this one cant be used

Answer (score 0):

A quick eample script to help you out:

```bat
@Echo Off
If /I Not "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" (PushD "%~dp0" 2>Nul || Exit/B)

Set "pExe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
Set "prTo=\\MOANB604\NLCAN02"
Set "pOpt=/N /T"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('DIR/B/A-D/ON *.pdf') Do "%pExe%" %pOpt% "%%A" "%prTo%"
```